# Combine source column values into one destination column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a source table which has the columns AreaCodeMobile + MobilePhoneNumber, AreaCodeHome + HomeNumber, AreaCodeOffice + OfficeNumber and I am wanting to combine these into one telephone column in my destination table. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff for instance I have a AreaCodeMobeile=833 and MobilePhoneNumber=7571256, I have areacodehome = 877 and homenumber = 2968997, I have a areacodeoffice = 247 and officenumber = 8658734 and I want to combine these all into one destination column called Telephonenumber so end result should have the full telephone number with the area code.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

What are the data types of those columns? Also, is it any format that you are looking to save in destination column?   If they are all int datatype, you need to use CAST to convert to varchar. For e.g.,

```
DECLARE @AreaCodeMobile int = 833, @MobilePhoneNumber INT = 7571256
DECLARE @areacodehome INT =  877, @homenumber INT =  2968997
DECLARE @areacodeoffice INT =  247 , @officenumber INT =  8658734

select CONCAT (
        'Mobile Phone Number: ' , cast(@areacodemobile as varchar(50)) , cast(@MobilePhoneNumber as varchar(50)) 
        ,' Home Number: ', CAST(@areacodehome as varchar(50)) , cast(@homenumber as varchar(50)) 
        ,' Office Number: ', CAST(@areacodeoffice as varchar(50)) , cast(@officenumber as varchar(50)) 
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use CONCAT.

And use `+` to prefix a comma, or whatever separator you prefere.

```
SELECT t.*, 
 CONCAT(AreaCodeMobile,
    ', '+MobilePhoneNumber, 
    ', '+AreaCodeHome,
    ', '+HomeNumber,
    ', '+AreaCodeOffice, 
    ', '+OfficeNumber) AS [Telephones]
FROM YourTable t;
```

The trick here is that CONCAT will ignore NULL's.
But a `+` will result to NULL if a NULL is added.
So then no useless comma's are added for the null's.

Or you could also use [CONCAT_WS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql), if your version of Sql Server supports it.

```
SELECT t.*, 
 CONCAT_WS(', ', AreaCodeMobile, MobilePhoneNumber, AreaCodeHome, HomeNumber, AreaCodeOffice, OfficeNumber) AS [Telephones]
FROM YourTable t;
```

So to update that column in your table, maybe something like this:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET Telephones = CONCAT_WS(', ', AreaCodeMobile, MobilePhoneNumber, AreaCodeHome, HomeNumber, AreaCodeOffice, OfficeNumber)
WHERE Telephones IS NULL;
```